# Google Cloud shell is killing my process after some time

Tags: firebase, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am running a java app using the google cloud shell and the app engine.
The application is running continuously and every 5 minutes it writes to Firestore Database a document using the Admin SDK with the proper authentication.
Yesterday it was killed after 2 hours and 20 minutes.
The 3 commands I am using to run it are the following.

```
mvn clean package
mvn package appengine:deploy -Dapp.deploy.projectId=myProjectIdHere
nohup mvn exec:exec -Dfirestore.project.id="myProjectIdHere" &> program.out &
```

Today the process was killed after 10 minutes.
Any ideas on how to fix that?

Comment: Is there any failure in the app? Maybe check the logs

Comment: program.out is not showing any errors!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud shell is a ephemeral VM that is killed after [few hours](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/limitations), this is designed for administrative tasks not for deployment.

If you need to run some process you could use an [always free Compute engine](https://cloud.google.com/free) VM (F1-micro instance), this F1 instance offers a better performance than the cloud shell.

Comment: That's exactly what I did and your answer is correct of course!